# Three.js MeshNormalMaterial default color

Tags: three.js

I'm working this three.js example - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-rotating-cube/

Here, the color of the cube changes every frame. However, nowhere in the example code, has the color been specified. Also, I tried specifying the color for the MeshNormalMaterial, but it doesn't have any effect. So, how is the color being manipulated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MeshNormalMaterial` uses `THREE.ShaderLib[ 'normal' ]` for the material's shader.

You can find the source in `WebGLShaders.js`.

The color is set in the fragment shader like so:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.5 * normalize( vNormal ) + 0.5, opacity );
```

You can see the that the color of the fragment is a function of the normal vector.

three.js r.62